# pyomo: Connector for blocks not working

Tags: python-3.x, pyomo

I'm trying to connect two blocks with the "Connector" class implemented in pyomo, using the following simple examplary code.

```
from pyomo.environ import *

m = ConcreteModel()

# Block 01
m.block_01 = Block()
m.block_01.flow = Var(within=NonNegativeReals, bounds=(2, 10))
m.block_01.OUT = Connector(initialize= {'flow': m.block_01.flow})

# Block 02
m.block_02 = Block()
m.block_02.flow = Var(within=NonNegativeReals)
m.block_02.IN = Connector(initialize= {'flow': m.block_02.flow})

m.con = Constraint(expr=m.block_01.OUT == m.block_02.IN)

def _obj(_m):
    return _m.block_01.flow + _m.block_02.flow
m.obj = Objective(rule=_obj)
```

After "optimization" all variables take their lower bound values (m.block_01.flow = 2 and m.block_02.flow = 0). So the Connector seems not to transfer any data for the variables.

If I'm using:

```
m.con = Constraint(expr=m.block_01.flow == m.block_02.flow)
```

instead, it works. However this is not the idea of Connectors, right?

Any ideas about the reason for the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you apply the `expand_connectors` transformation before sending your model to a solver?

```
TransformationFactory('core.expand_connectors').apply_to(m)
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot! Unfortunately there was no information available in "The Book" on how to apply connectors. Would be helpful for the next edition.